# Problemas al ejecutar sentencia UPDATE en MySQL + WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

Estoy intentando actualizar una serie de productos que al introducirlos en la tienda WooCommerce, algunas etiquetas son erróneas. Como debe ser un cambio masivo, lo he querido hacer por `MySQL`.

Primero, he sacado los productos que corresponden con el patrón erróneo:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_name, b.term_id, b.name, c.object_id,c.term_taxonomy_id
FROM wp_strposts a, wp_strterms b, wp_strterm_relationships c
WHERE c.object_id = a.ID and c.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_id and a.post_name like '%plata%' and b.term_id = 41
ORDER BY a.ID desc;
```

Esto me devuelve aquellos productos que tienen en su nombre la palabra plata, pero se le ha asignado una etiqueta errónea de oro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es cambiar el campo `term_taxonomy_id` cuyo valor sea 41 (etiqueta oro) por 52 (etiqueta plata).

He preparado la siguiente sentencia:

```
update wp_strterm_relationships set term_taxonomy_id = 52 where object_id in (1234,
1232,
1231,
1226,
1222,
1196,
1189,
1184,
1182,
1180,
1177,
1166,
1160,
1152);
```

Pero al ejecutarla me da el siguiente error:

`#1062 - Entrada duplicada '1152-52' para la clave 'PRIMARY'`

Por más que miro no entiendo que fallo de clave primaria me está dando. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Esta columna `term_taxonomy_id` es foránea u otra primaria? Si es así no puedes modificar; a menos que elimines la relación.

Comment: Imagino que es la clave primaria de la tabla wp_strterms propagada a tabla de wp_strterm_relationship. Pero no entiendo porque no me deja cambiarlo ahí, si se trata de una tabla que recoge las relaciones entre producto y etiquetas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado el problema haciendo una actualización manual por `phpMyAdmin`.

La sentencia `UPDATE` que publico en mi pregunta está incompleta o mal formulada, por eso da el error. Cuando le estoy diciendo que actualice la etiqueta de todos esos ID, no le había añadido en el `WHERE` que el campo que debe buscar tiene el valor 41 (del oro).

Esta sentencia si funciona:

```sql
update wp_strterm_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = 52 where wp_strterm_relationships.object_id in (1232,
1231,
1226,
1222,
1196,
1189,
1184,
1182,
1180,
1177,
1166,
1160,
1152) and wp_strterm_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 41;
```

Answer (score 1):

EL error indica que ya existe en `wp_strterm_relationships`  un registro con `object_id`=1152 y `term_taxonomy_id`=52 (aparte del registro que muestras con `term_taxonomy_id`=41), lo que indica que ese elemento ya tenia asignada la etiqueta 'oro' tambien.

En este caso de duplicado el UPDATE no es necesario, sino simplemente DELETE.

Para que la consulta se ejecute sin problema, tu lista de ids debe descartar los que ya tienen `term_taxonomy_id`=52 (se permite tener mas de una etiqueta).

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_name, b.term_id, b.name, c.object_id,c.term_taxonomy_id
FROM wp_strposts a, wp_strterms b, wp_strterm_relationships c
WHERE c.object_id = a.ID and c.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_id and a.post_name like '%plata%' and b.term_id = 41 
AND 51 NOT IN (select r.term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_strterm_relationships r WHERE r.object_id=a.ID)
ORDER BY a.ID desc;
```

Puedes ejecutar el UPDATE:

```
UPDATE wp_strterm_relationships set term_taxonomy_id = 52 
WHERE object_id in ( ... )
```

Y finalmente eliminar las etiquetas plata donde tengan ambas:

```
DELETE c.*
FROM wp_strposts a, wp_strterms b, wp_strterm_relationships c
WHERE c.object_id = a.ID and c.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_id and a.post_name like '%plata%' and b.term_id = 41 
AND 51 IN (select r.term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_strterm_relationships r WHERE r.object_id=a.ID)
```

Finalmente, el manejo de taxonomias se puede realizar usando codigo con las funciones `wp_set_object_terms()` y `wp_remove_object_terms()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remove_object_terms/

Comment: El SELECT que has indicado me devuelve cero filas. Es decir, no hay productos que tengan ambas etiquetas. Eso lo tengo comprobado incluso en el propio WordPress, ya que o tienen plata o tienen oro.

Comment: Es muy probable que el objeto id 1152 ya se haya actualizado en un UPDATE previo, ya que usabas una lista de IDs fijos podria pasar. Veo que al agregar el filtro por term_taxonomy_id has evitado eso que los elementos ya actualizados se incluyan.

Comment: No lo descarto, aunque desde la primera vez que lancé el update me dio fallo. Aún así, ya está solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

Pudiste haber usado la propia consulta `SELECT` de verificación haciendo un `JOIN`

```
UPDATE wp_strterm_relationships t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.ID 
    FROM wp_strposts a, wp_strterms b, wp_strterm_relationships c
    WHERE c.object_id = a.ID and c.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_id 
          and a.post_name like '%plata%' 
          and b.term_id = 41
) tmp ON tmp.ID = t.object_id
SET t.term_taxonomy_id = 52;
```

Esta consulta te actualizaría la columna `term_taxonomy_id` a `52` en todas las coincidencias de lo que hayas puesto en la sub-consulta.

**AVISO:** Antes de actualizaciones masivas, haz una copia de seguridad de la(s) tabla(s) que vayas a actualizar.